# list comprehension on multiple lists of lists

Tags: python, regex

I am struck on an awkward lists comprehension problem, which I am not able to solve. So, I have two lists looking like the following:

```
a=[[....],[....],[....]]
b=[[....],[....],[....]]
len(a)==len(b) including sublists i.e sublists also have the same dimension.
```

Now I want to do a re.compile which looks something like:

```
[re.compile(_subelement_in_a).search(_subelement_in_b).group(1)]
```

and I am wondering how I can achieve the above using list compherension - something like:

```
[[re.compile(str(x)).search(str(y)).group(1) for x in a] for y in b]
```

..but obviously the above does not seem to work and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

*EDIT*

I have just realized that the sublists of b have more elements than the sublists of a. So, for example:

```
a=[[1 items],[1 items],[1 items]]
b=[[10 item], [10 item], [10 item]]
```

I would still like to do the same as my above question:

```
[[re.compile(str(x)).search(str(y)).group(1) for x in b] for y in a]
```

and the output looking like:

```
c = [[b[0] in a[0] items],[b[1] in a[1] items],[b[2] in a[2] items]]
```

Example:

```
a=[["hgjkhukhkh"],["78hkugkgkug"],["ukkhukhylh"]]
b=[[r"""a(.*?)b""",r"""c(.*?)d""",r"""e(.*?)f""",r"""g(.*?)h""",r"""i(.*?)j"""],[r"""k(.*?)l""",r"""m(.*?)n""",r"""o(.*?)p""",r"""q(.*?)r"""],[r"""s(.*?)t""",r"""u(.*?)v""",r"""x(.*?)y""",r"""z(.*?)>"""]]
```

using one to one mapping. i.e check if:

```
elements of sublists of b[0] are present in sublist element of a[0]
elements of sublists of b[1] are present in sublist element of a[1]
elements of sublists of b[2] are presnet in sublist element of a[2]
```

Comment: Changing the problem parameters like this suggest you didn't give the question a good try in the first place, since you didn't notice the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you think you must solve this with a list comprehension? Are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Yes, I am open to any solution really. I just thought list comprehension is a good solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `zip`? It takes a pair of lists and turns it into a list of pairs.

```
[
    [my_operation(x,y) for x,y in zip(xs, ys)]
    for xs, ys in zip(a, b)
]
```

-- Edit. Requirements changed:

```
[
    [[regex(p, s) for p in patterns] for s in strings]
    for strings, patterns in zip(a, b)
]
```

Comment: I apologize for the error - It was an oversight. I have included an example if that helps.

Comment: @user2152572: Looks like in the inner list you should use `for x in xs for y in ys` instead of using zip again. Nesting the fors like that makes the list comprehension cover all the conbinations of x with y.

Comment: I have been trying to use something like: [[re.compile(x).search(y).group(1) for x in b] for y in a] but this does not work.

Comment: @user2152572. See my edit. In the first level you want to use zip to get each pair of lists. In the inner level you just have to use "simple" lists comprehensions like you already know how to do.

Comment: your edit does not seem to work - I will keep trying and update.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` liberally:

```
[[re.search(x, y).group(1) for x,y in zip(s,t)] for s,t in zip(a,b)]
```

The first `zip(a,b)` produces lists of sublist pairs. The second `zip` pairs the elements in parallel sublists together.

Comment: I have just made an edit to the question - the subelements of b have more elements than the subelements of a - wondering if your solution still applies. I tried it and it does not work for this case.

Comment: Well, no, but you said the sublists were the same dimension. You've invalidated that. You also now have to specify how you'd want the excess elements to wrap (mirror? repeat? fill?) among other problems. You're better off just padding the `a` sublists.

Comment: hmm.. Could you please explain what you mean by padding the a sublists? To be clear, In "b" I have a list of regex'es (say dim 100) in each sublist to evaluate against each sublist elements of "a" - if this makes sense.

Comment: Making them the same length somehow. I do not know what problem you are really trying to solve (see: [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)).

Comment: I am VERY sorry about that - I made a mistake - I have included an example if that helps. Again, sorry about my oversight on the problem. p.s: the XY problem did teach me something!